# cmake : failing to link against google profiler (gperftools)

Tags: c++, cmake, profiler, catkin, gperftools

I am on ubuntu 16.04.

Here what I did:

1. installed gperftools :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install google-perftools libgoogle-perftools-dev
   ```
2. downloaded FindGperftools.cmake from: https://github.com/vast-io/vast/blob/master/cmake/FindGperftools.cmake
3. renamed `FindGperftools.cmake` to `GperftoolsConfig.cmake` and placed it in a `cmake` folder in my package
4. added to `CMakelists.txt`:

   ```
   set (Gperftools_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake/")
   find_package(Gperftools REQUIRED)
   ```
5. in same CMakelists.txt, link my executable:

   ```
   target_link_libraries(my_executable ${GPERFTOOLS_PROFILER})
   ```
6. in a terminal, export the CPUPROFILE environment variable:

   ```
   export CPUPROFILE=/my_path/prof.out
   ```
7. in the same terminal, run the executable:

   ```
   ./my_executable
   ```

There is no error message, but the log file `/my_path/prof.out` is not created.

If I run "ldd" on "my_executable", it does not show any linkage against profiler (`ldd ./my_executable | grep profil` does not result in anything).
Yet, when looking at files in the build folder, the compiler seems to do the linkage (`-lprofile` is there).

Anything I may have forgotten?

Note: not sure it is relevant, but I use catkin.

Comment: Probably, it is unrelated with a problem, but renaming "Find" script to "Config" one is not a common usage of CMake: while purposes of those scripts are similar, the scripts are run in different "environments". E.g., `find_package_handle_standard_args` used in "Find" script has no sence in "Config" script. For find "Find" script itself set *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* CMake variable.

Comment: Is it possible you defined the wrong variable? In the link you provided a comment says `Gperftools_ROOT_DIR`  `Set this variable to the root installation of Gperftools`  Which is different than `Gperftools_DIR` from your answer

Answer (score 1):

This looks like ubuntu's (and non-standard) linker feature to not link libraries which symbols are directly not used. Try adding -Wl,-no-as-needed to your LDFLAGS (and make sure it is passed before -lprofiler).